# Vanishing contacts, what can I do?

Tags: contacts, 2.3-gingerbread

On my old Android 2.3 phone there are some contacts that are not available in the contacts app (either manually or by searching), but when I type the number into the dialled app, the contacts appear.

Is there any way to get those contacts back so that I can get them in my new Android Marshmellow phone?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:- These contacts were imported from the SIM to the phone to make room for more contacts on the SIM.

Also I have already seen [A contact can not be found by name in dialer but exists in contacts](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/137197/16575) and followed the instructions but they don't work. There are also some differences such as mine are stored on the phone and on Android 2.3.

UPDATE:- I had a chat with Samsung Support and they told me to "Kindly go to the Setting> search for Application manager> All > tap left touch button >Reset app preferences> reset apps. Kindly restart your device after that." I'll try this later when I can and get back.

Comment: Are these contacts stored on SIM? Id yes, exporting from SIM may help

Comment: No, they were stored on the phone after being imported from SIM. They are not synced to Google Contacts and are not available on VCard backup exports.